# Round float to NSNumber got NaN

Tags: ios, nan, nsnumber

I have a float latitude, and I'd like to precise 6 digits for the fractional part. 
When I do

```
NSNumber * nLatitude = @(round(latitude*1e6)/1e6);
NSLog(@"%f %@", latitude, nLatitude);
```

Sometimes I got right result:

```
48.8282641210 48.828264
```

Other times I got NaN:

```
48.8281686092  nan
```

Anyone has an idea?

---

Thanks for all your responses. Indeed the NSNumberFormatter solves the problem, I'd like to find still the origin of problem. 
Rounding numbers is for saving disk spaces and better readability. It's for logging large amount of locations.

Here are some more details:

I have a trace and I simulate the change of location on simulator. Positions are sent by a FakeLocationManager with a timer.

```
- (void)locationManager:(FakeLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocation:(CLLocation *)location{
     // Here the code I round floats
}
```

Sometimes repeated locations are sent, first ones worked correctly and then a same position turned out a NaN. It seems to me that the cause could be the timer.

Comment: Just as a comment for large numbers like that you can just do `1e6` instead of 1000000 because it's easier to read that way.

Comment: how do you mean _other times_? what is different _other times_? something must be different _other times_ because the code is not working like a drama-queen...

Comment: I could not reproduce the error.

Comment: Why do you need to round the number?

Answer (score 3):

I have rarely needed to care about the number of decimal places of a floating point value.

I suspect the issue is one of presentation, in which case `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` can be used to specify the number of decimal places of the floating point value:

```
_myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6f", [nLatitude doubleValue]];
//                                           ^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

use this `[NSString stringwithFormat:@"%.4f",[nLatitude floatValue]];`